# Monotorrent transfer files

Tags: file, transfer, monotorrent

I would like to use monotorrent in a project for transferring files between two computers. Unfortunately I could not find documentation on how to do this. More exactly, there is an example with the source code on how to download files using this library but I could not found examples on how to upload my files using it. Is there some code example for this?

Comment: The torrent protocol isn't an ideal choice for direct file share between two machines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the tiers that were added at the creation of the torrent. It appears that they must end with `announce/`

```
RawTrackerTier tier = new RawTrackerTier();
tier.Add("http://127.0.0.1:10000/announce/");
```